# Java REGEX .replaceall() not working on specific JSON object (converted to string)

Tags: java, json, regex

I'm trying to remove all the slashes out of a JSON Object and then add it to an array list. Here is what it looks like regardless of what I type into Regex:
I also want to remove the brackets and duplicate strings, but even trying to remove the slashes isn't working so I'm trying to build it up. Just as a test I've tried replacing anything and everything in the String, but no matter what I pick (even alpha numerics) it doesn't work.

**Example output for an item in the category list:** 
"[[\"Mediterranean\",\"mediterranean\"],[\"Greek\",\"greek\"]]"

```
private static final ArrayList<String> BusinessIDList = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> RatingList = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> cityList = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> stateList = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static void queryAPI(YelpAPI yelpApi, YelpAPICLI yelpApiCli) {

    String searchResponseJSON = yelpApi.searchForBusinessesByLocation(yelpApiCli.term, yelpApiCli.location);

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject response = null;
    try {
        response = (JSONObject) parser.parse(searchResponseJSON);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        System.out.println("Error: could not parse JSON response:");
        System.out.println(searchResponseJSON);
        System.exit(1);
    }


    JSONArray businesses = (JSONArray) response.get("businesses");

    for (int i = 0; i < businesses.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) businesses.get(i);
        JSONObject temp1 = (JSONObject) temp.get("location");

        BusinessIDList.add(temp.get("id").toString());
        RatingList.add(temp.get("rating").toString());
        cityList.add(temp1.get("city").toString());
        stateList.add(temp1.get("state_code").toString());
        phoneList.add(temp.get("phone").toString());

        String tempCat = temp.get("categories").toString();
        tempCat = tempCat.replaceAll("\\\\", " ");
        categoryList.add(tempCat);

        String tempAdr = temp1.get("address").toString();
        tempAdr = tempAdr.replaceAll("\\\\", " ");
        addressList.add(tempAdr);

        nameList.add(temp.get("name").toString());

    }
```

Comment: Let's keep this simple; `String t="[[\\\"Med\\\",\\\"med\\\"]"; t = t.replaceAlll("\\\\",""); System.out.println(t);`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, however your code is incomplete and cannot be run on its own. Could you please post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Sure one sec, sorry about that.

Comment: The new code is certainly not minimal nor complete. If you want people to help you, you must provide code and input data that make it (easily) runnable to reproduce the problem. Please read the [mcve] help page carefully.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to make a JSON object out of thin air, I only know how to get data from them. Sorry.

Comment: What I'm saying is, only you can fix your code. You ask a question about why a pattern is not matching or replacing as expected, and you show an example where we see a pattern, and you tell us what the input is but then claim the output is not changed. Well. Just try one line. All by itself. `System.out.println("[[\\\"Iknow\\\",\\\"whatImDoing\\\"]]".replaceAll("\\\\",""));` I think you'll find your problem has nothing to do with the pattern, nor `replaceAll` but is somewhere else.

Comment: Could you post the code where you output/check the contents of `categoryList`? Or do you just check them through the debugger?

Answer (score 3):

You're not assigning `tempCat` to the return value of `replaceAll`.
Try changing:

```
tempCat.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", " ");
```

to

```
tempCat = tempCat.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", " ");
```

For more information about the `replaceAll` method, see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Edit: Sorry, updated with the correct link.

Comment: No cigar on that one. Sorry I had deleted that earlier to try it as a possible solution.